# Java - Send Message to all Clients

Tags: java

I'm creating a chat server using Socket Servers and Thread. I have 3 Classes in my Server ChatServer.java, ThreadedServer.java, and Main.java. My Client has 2 ChatClient.java, Main.java. I need to make it so when a message is sent in from a client to server, the server sends out the message to all Clients.

ChatServer.java

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatServer {
    protected Socket s;
    protected Socket ss;
    public ChatServer() {
        try {
             ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6969);
             Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                 public void main(String []args) throws IOException {
                    ss.close();
                }
            });
            while (true) {
                Socket s =ss.accept();
                new ThreadedServer(s).start();
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        new ThreadedServer(s).start();
      }
}
```

ThreadedServer.java

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ThreadedServer extends Thread{
    protected Socket socket;

    public ThreadedServer(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while (true) {
                String str=(String)dis.readUTF();
                String remote = socket.getInetAddress().toString();
                String newmes = remote + ": " + str;
                dos.writeUTF(newmes);
                System.out.println(newmes);
                if (str.toUpperCase() == "QUIT") {
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }else if (str.toUpperCase() == "EXIT") {
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java (Server)
    package server;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatServer chat = new ChatServer();
    }
}
```

Here are the Client.java's

ChatClient.java
    package client;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatClient {

    public ChatClient() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("10.4.27.29",6969);
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                public void main(String []args) throws IOException {
                    s.close();
                }
            });
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                String message = System.console().readLine();
                dos.writeUTF(message);
                System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java (Client)

```
package client;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatClient chat = new ChatClient();

    }
}
```

Please any help would be amazing.

Also any ideas to make this nicer would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Regarding "making this nicer". Consider using non-blocking sockets IO. Regarding sending the message to all clients: Keep a Set of sockets on your server, and send the message to each of the sockets connected but the one being sent from

Answer (score 1):

Try running this. This is one I made that works.

ChatServer.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashSet;

/**
 * A multithreaded chat room server.  When a client connects the
 * server requests a screen name by sending the client the
 * text "SUBMITNAME", and keeps requesting a name until
 * a unique one is received.  After a client submits a unique
 * name, the server acknowledges with "NAMEACCEPTED".  Then
 * all messages from that client will be broadcast to all other
 * clients that have submitted a unique screen name.  The
 * broadcast messages are prefixed with "MESSAGE ".
 *
 * Because this is just a teaching example to illustrate a simple
 * chat server, there are a few features that have been left out.
 * Two are very useful and belong in production code:
 *
 *     1. The protocol should be enhanced so that the client can
 *        send clean disconnect messages to the server.
 *
 *     2. The server should do some logging.
 */
public class ChatServer {

    /**
     * The port that the server listens on.
     */
    private static final int PORT = 9001;

    /**
     * The set of all names of clients in the chat room.  Maintained
     * so that we can check that new clients are not registering name
     * already in use.
     */
    private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    /**
     * The set of all the print writers for all the clients.  This
     * set is kept so we can easily broadcast messages.
     */
    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();

    /**
     * The appplication main method, which just listens on a port and
     * spawns handler threads.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The chat server is running.");
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    try {
        while (true) {
        new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
    }

    /**
     * A handler thread class.  Handlers are spawned from the listening
     * loop and are responsible for a dealing with a single client
     * and broadcasting its messages.
     */
    private static class Handler extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    /**
         * Constructs a handler thread, squirreling away the socket.
         * All the interesting work is done in the run method.
         */
    public Handler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /**
         * Services this thread's client by repeatedly requesting a
         * screen name until a unique one has been submitted, then
         * acknowledges the name and registers the output stream for
         * the client in a global set, then repeatedly gets inputs and
         * broadcasts them.
         */
    public void run() {
        try {

        // Create character streams for the socket.
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                  socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // Request a name from this client.  Keep requesting until
        // a name is submitted that is not already used.  Note that
        // checking for the existence of a name and adding the name
        // must be done while locking the set of names.
        while (true) {
            out.println("SUBMITNAME");
            name = in.readLine();
            if (name == null) {
            return;
            }
            synchronized (names) {
            if (!names.contains(name)) {
                names.add(name);
                break;
            }
            }
        }

        // Now that a successful name has been chosen, add the
        // socket's print writer to the set of all writers so
        // this client can receive broadcast messages.
        out.println("NAMEACCEPTED");
        writers.add(out);

        // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
        // Ignore other clients that cannot be broadcasted to.
        while (true) {
            String input = in.readLine();
            if (input == null) {
            return;
            }
            for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
            writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
            }
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
        // This client is going down!  Remove its name and its print
        // writer from the sets, and close its socket.
        if (name != null) {
            names.remove(name);
        }
        if (out != null) {
            writers.remove(out);
        }
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

ChatClient.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * A simple Swing-based client for the chat server.  Graphically
 * it is a frame with a text field for entering messages and a
 * textarea to see the whole dialog.
 *
 * The client follows the Chat Protocol which is as follows.
 * When the server sends "SUBMITNAME" the client replies with the
 * desired screen name.  The server will keep sending "SUBMITNAME"
 * requests as long as the client submits screen names that are
 * already in use.  When the server sends a line beginning
 * with "NAMEACCEPTED" the client is now allowed to start
 * sending the server arbitrary strings to be broadcast to all
 * chatters connected to the server.  When the server sends a
 * line beginning with "MESSAGE " then all characters following
 * this string should be displayed in its message area.
 */
public class ChatClient {

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chatter");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
    JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8, 40);

    /**
     * Constructs the client by laying out the GUI and registering a
     * listener with the textfield so that pressing Return in the
     * listener sends the textfield contents to the server.  Note
     * however that the textfield is initially NOT editable, and
     * only becomes editable AFTER the client receives the NAMEACCEPTED
     * message from the server.
     */
    public ChatClient() {

    // Layout GUI
    textField.setEditable(false);
    messageArea.setEditable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField, "North");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), "Center");
    frame.pack();

    // Add Listeners
    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        /**
         * Responds to pressing the enter key in the textfield by sending
         * the contents of the text field to the server.    Then clear
         * the text area in preparation for the next message.
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            out.println(textField.getText());
            textField.setText("");
        }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the address of the server.
     */
    private String getServerAddress() {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                       frame,
                       "Enter IP Address of the Server:",
                       "Welcome to the Chatter",
                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Prompt for and return the desired screen name.
     */
    private String getName() {
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                       frame,
                       "Choose a screen name:",
                       "Screen name selection",
                       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the server then enters the processing loop.
     */
    private void run() throws IOException {

    // Make connection and initialize streams
    String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                              socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
    while (true) {
        String line = in.readLine();
        if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
        out.println(getName());
        } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
        textField.setEditable(true);
        } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
        messageArea.append(line.substring(8) + "\n");
        }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Runs the client as an application with a closeable frame.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
    client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    client.frame.setVisible(true);
    client.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to add it to my code. This may sound snarky, but I would like it to work with my code, cause i'm trying to build from the ground up and couldn't figure this concept out.

Comment: Well then look at my example, then just implement similar logic to yours. You don't need to use my entire code, but having a "working example" of what you want helps. I am using java swing on my client, but that doesn't mean that you have to.