# Implement web socket local server in Swing application

Tags: java, swing, websocket, java-websocket

I am not able to find any implementation of a WS or WSS web socket server created in a Java Swing desktop application.

I am planning to govern multiple clients using a local server, imagine chat room on a local LAN, but I do not wish to host/run Tomcat or Jetty etc to host the server, I want it to be a Java Swing application that I can copy paste on any machine to make it the server and it can have the same chat features.

**UPDATE:**
Found some very useful topic : [Java - Send Message to all Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185206/java-send-message-to-all-clients)
Will follow this.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in this realm, but this might help…

Wikipedia maintains [a list of WebSocket implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations), both client and server.

You may be interested in the open-source [*Atmosphere Framework*](https://github.com/Atmosphere). It supports working with WebSocket but I am not clear if it actually is a server implementation.

Perhaps check open-source projects like [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org) or [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) or [WildFly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly) to see if their WebSocket implementation might be modularized sufficiently to plug into your app.

Comment: Thanks..not exactly what I was looking for but I will give it a try..